# Trying to install keras/tensorflow for Spyder but getting nowhere

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've tried going through anaconda as well, but can't seem to get it to work. I like working in the Spyder IDE so would prefer to stay in there.

Python version: 3.9.6
Pip version: 23.1.2

I've done "pip install tensorflow" and it says numerous requirements already verified. Same thing with "pip install keras". In my python script, I try "import keras" and get the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.compat'. There's no problem importing tensorflow itself, however I can't print the version of it: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '_ _ version _ _'

Update: when trying something simple with tensorflow like acos(), I get a similar error: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'acos'. I don't know why this is happening, I have reinstalled tensorflow to ensure it is current

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you have followed all the steps mentioned in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native_1) to install tensorflow using conda.

Now install and launch Spyder through Anaconda Navigator by selecting same Virtual Environment where you have installed tensorflow.

I tried the same code with same configuration which did not show any error.
(Please check the replicated code screenshot as below:)

[image]